# RSolve - basic question about using rules as functions

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

I think this is basic question, but I can't find it in Help... (I am begginer :P)

I have this expression
`RSolve[{a[n + 2] - 12542 a[n + 1] + a[n] == 0, a[0] == 82, 
  a[1] == 1028302}, a[n], n]`

and it returns list with solution as rule
`a[n]-> etc`
How do I use and evaluate this function?
I need it do that `a[3]` returns its value at 3?

Comment: Look up `/.`.${}$

Comment: I need whole function, because I need to use it for more values in loop?

Comment: Yes, so did you look up `/.` as well as the docs for `RSolve[]`?

Comment: (1) Use `soln=RSolve[...]; a[n]/. soln /. n->3`  or (2) Change the second argument of `RSolve` to `a` (instead of `a[n]`) to get a pure function and use `a[3]`.

Comment: @kglr Thank you,  it worked for me, but value is in braces, as part of list. How could I  have it without being part of list, 
(I set` f[n_]=a[n] /. soln`    and for `f[0.]` I got `{82.}`. How could I get values without braces?

Comment: @Meow you can use `soln[[1]]` instead of `soln`.

Comment: @kglr: Thank you :P It worked great (and I'm sorry for stupid questions, I am still begginer in this :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f,a,n]
(* solve for `a` instead of `a[n]` *)
soln = RSolve[{a[n + 2] - 12542 a[n + 1] + a[n] == 0, a[0] == 82, 
    a[1] == 1028302}, a, n];
(* assign to `f` if you wish *)
f = a /. First@soln;
(* use `f` *)
f[3.]
```

Answer (score 1):

I only post this as `RSolve` does provide the desired formula but application produces expressions with radicals that require simplification. As this is a linear recursive relation it may be simpler to just produce values recursively, e.g.

```
m = {{12542, -1}, {0, 1}};
v = {1028302, 82};
a[0] = v[[2]];
a[1] = v[[1]];

a[n_?(# > 1 &)] := First@MatrixPower[m, n - 1].v;
```